# reading an ISO-8859-1 encoded data from CSV

Tags: java, csv, utf-8, iso-8859-1

I have a CSV file, which I need to read and analyse. I use the methods and classes in from Apache Commons CSV. 
The input file uses the regular low ASCII (0x0 -0x7f) characters. Some of fields include also line breaks. 
However, in addition, some of the fields may contain characters 0xe4 and 0xe5 which need to be converted to '{' and '}' respectively. I have looked at the input file with a hex view so I am certain that it is really 0xe4 and 0xe5, and not some Unicode.

```
FileReader in = new FileReader(INPUT_CSV);
System.out.println(in.getEncoding());
records = CSVFormat.RFC4180.withFirstRecordAsHeader().withDelimiter('|').withQuote('#').parse(in);
```

The getEncoding() method says that the file is UTF-8 encoded, and I suspect this is where it goes wrong.

Then I read the records by using a loop through

```
for (CSVRecord record : records) {
// some analysis in here
   String toProcess = record.get("TO_PROCESS"); // this is the field which may contain the 0xe4 and 0xe5
   toProcess = StringUtils.replaceChars(toProcess, OPENING_BRACKET,'{');
   toProcess = StringUtils.replaceChars(toProcess, CLOSING_BRACKET,'}');

}
```

Yet, this replacement does not work, and the output strings have a three character sequence 0xef 0xbf 0xbd instead of the brackets I was hoping to see.

Is it possible to force the ISO-8859-1 on the input? Or while reading the strings from the input file?

p.s.
Opening and closing brackets are defined as

```
    static char OPENING_BRACKET = 228; // 'ä'
    static char CLOSING_BRACKET = 229; // 'å'
```

Comment: The `FileReader` constructor with one argument will always use the platform default encoding. Since Java 11 you can use the two-argument constructors to provide the correct encoding, before Java 11 you'll have to create a `FileInputStream` and wrap it with an `InputStreamReader` to which you can provide the encoding.

Comment: Thank you very much Joachim! This solved the problem.